# Setting Variable Path to Template Directory inside Script

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, scripts

I have **HTML5 Template** with 5 pages. I am converting it to a **WordPress Theme**.

I have a contact page. This page includes 'forms.js' script to send contact form data to 'MailHandler.php' file.

Inside the 'forms.js' script there is a variable I want to change,

```
mailHandlerURL:'bat/MailHandler.php'
```

How do I change this to something like the following?

```
mailHandlerURL:<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>'/bat/MailHandler.php'
```

The PHP is not working inside this script. Please help.

Comment: you don't have to provide absolute url, just use the relative path to MailHandler.php

Comment: Is that AJAX form and you need MailHandler.php for that?

Comment: @HameedullahKhan it does not work that way. I tried...

Comment: @Mamaduka No. It is just a POSTing to the MailHandler.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the url of the website, or other server side calculated values, to JavaScript you can use `wp_localize_script` ([Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)). This function creates an object, with the values you've passed.

As the documentation states, you've got to include your script with `wp_enqueue_script`, else it doesn't call localize_script. Also make sure to call `wp_head()` before your closing head tags, to make it work.

Comment: Thanks. this is the exact answer I was looking after. I just couldn't find it. Thanks martinCzerwi!

Answer (score 0):

If the code itself is small, then I think you should call it inside theme file, as shown here in the below example.

**Example -**

```
<script>
mailHandlerURL:<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>'/bat/MailHandler.php'
</script>
```

> #### Note -
>
> By The Way, you can not use the Wordpress functions outside, unless you import `wp-blog-header.php` -
>
> **Example -**
>
> ```
> require_once('./blog/wp-blog-header.php');`
> ```

Comment: Yes that method works. But script is somewhat long and I prefer an alternative method..